# Java: How to iterate through an array of type linked lists and append those to an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, linked-list, radix

For homework in an algorithms class we had to write a program that implemented a Radix sort algorithm.  I ended up implementing it in a round about way, and it functions correctly.  However there is a part of my code that is an atrocious looking if else block in a for loop.  I have to retrieve the items out of an array of linked lists in the correct order and add the elements back into an Integer array. One of my classmates and I spent quite a while trying to figure out how to put this block into for loops but could just not come up with a to do that. So that's my questions, how would I put the objects of the linked lists in an array into a different array.  The code I came up for the sort method is below:

```
private static Integer[] sort(Integer[] input, int place){
    //create an array of linked lists
    LinkedList<Integer>[] bucketsOut = new LinkedList[10];

    //initialize the linked lists
    for(int i=0; i < 10; i++){
        bucketsOut[i] = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    }

    int bucketPlacement = 0;
    //place every input into the correct bucket
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        bucketPlacement = getDigit(input[i].intValue(), place);
        bucketsOut[bucketPlacement].add(input[i]);
    }

    //Place the elements out of the linked lists into the correct place in input[]
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++){ //for each input number
        if(bucketsOut[0].peekFirst() != null){  
            input[i] = bucketsOut[0].pollFirst().intValue();
        }else if(bucketsOut[1].peekFirst() != null){    
            input[i] = bucketsOut[1].pollFirst().intValue();
        }else if(bucketsOut[2].peekFirst() != null){    
            input[i] = bucketsOut[2].pollFirst().intValue();
        }else if(bucketsOut[3].peekFirst() != null){    
            input[i] = bucketsOut[3].pollFirst().intValue();
        }else if(bucketsOut[4].peekFirst() != null){    
            input[i] = bucketsOut[4].pollFirst().intValue();
        }else if(bucketsOut[5].peekFirst() != null){    
            input[i] = bucketsOut[5].pollFirst().intValue();
        }else if(bucketsOut[6].peekFirst() != null){    
            input[i] = bucketsOut[6].pollFirst().intValue();
        }else if(bucketsOut[7].peekFirst() != null){    
            input[i] = bucketsOut[7].pollFirst().intValue();
        }else if(bucketsOut[8].peekFirst() != null){    
            input[i] = bucketsOut[8].pollFirst().intValue();
        }else if(bucketsOut[9].peekFirst() != null){    
            input[i] = bucketsOut[9].pollFirst().intValue();
        }
    }
    //return sorted list for digit
    return input;
}
```

Comment: You pull the first element from all arrays, and then go back to the second element in all arrays.  Is that intentional?

Comment: (@markspace : don't think so - look at all those `else`s.) If your environment had a `CompositeCollection` like [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/collection/CompositeCollection.html), you could instantiate one for [`toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray-T:A-) (to be followed by a [`System.arraycopy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-), if need be).

Comment: My code works for numbers up to max_int positive numbers. I didn't originally upload the whole thing as to not take up space, so here is my completed code in pastebin: [link](http://pastebin.com/BzJ45241)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to greybeard for pointing out that the `else`s above actually causes the first bucket to be emptied completely first.

With that in mind, its not too hard to turn this into a loop.  Remember, your basic idea is that you first want to copy all of the items in the first bucket.  This is easily done with a `while` loop.

```
     while( bucketsOut[bucketIndex].peekFirst() != null &&
             inputIndex < input.length ) 
     {
        input[inputIndex++] = bucketsOut[bucketIndex].pollFirst();
     }
```

So here, for each bucket, we copy until the `peek` value is null.  Notice I use post-increment inside the array index.  This is really common when you need to copy some number of elements into an array.  It allows me to copy to increasing elements while not having to fix in advance the exact number with a `for` loop.

With that, the rest is pretty easy.  I just added a for loop around the while loop to increment to the next bucket.  The `while` loop checks `inputIndex` so we don't accidentally try to copy beyond the end of `input`.

```
  for( int inputIndex = 0, bucketIndex = 0; bucketIndex < bucketsOut.length;
          bucketIndex++ ) 
  {
     while( bucketsOut[bucketIndex].peekFirst() != null &&
             inputIndex < input.length ) 
     {
        input[inputIndex++] = bucketsOut[bucketIndex].pollFirst();
     }
  }
```

If you want to be fancy (or if you have many more elements) you might add a manual test at the after the while loop so you don't have to test for more buckets if `input` is full.

```
     if( inputIndex >= input.length ) break;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have a series of operations that are exactly the same except for the change in an index, it means that you can do it in a `for` loop:

**First attempt**

```
for (int j = 0; j < bucketsOut.length; j++ ) {
    // The part that is repeated again and again
    if (bucketsOut[j].peekFirst() != null) {
        input[i] = bucketsOut[j].pollFirst().intValue();
    }
}
```

But wait! This will continue through all the buckets. Your original `if` structure actually meant that once you hit the right `if`, you would not be looking at any of the other `else`s.

This can be done by *breaking out of the loop* when the condition becomes true:

**Improved version**

```
for (int j = 0; j < bucketsOut.length; j++ ) {
    if (bucketsOut[j].peekFirst() != null) {
        input[i] = bucketsOut[j].pollFirst().intValue();
        break; // Now the j loop will stop when we hit the first non-null.
    }
}
```

Or you could use enhanced for - the logic is the same:

```
for ( LinkedList<Integer> bucket : bucketsOut ) {
    if (bucket.peekFirst() != null) {
        input[i] = bucket.pollFirst().intValue();
        break; 
    }
}
```

Comment: (This would seem less mistakable if it mentioned that these loops are still to be in an outer loop iterating `input` by incrementing `i`.)

Comment: @greybeard I thought that would be obvious since the code still refers to `i` in the input index.